# Cannot call member function without object. C++

Tags: c++, function, object, vector

I'm making a merge sort class that has functions that take in a vector, sort it and return it.
It looks like this:

```
class MergeSort {
  public:
    template <class T>
    static vector<T> sort (vector<T> a)

{
    if (a.size()<=1)
    {
        return a;
    }

    else

    {

        //some code here(seperating the vector
        vector<T> left=sort(leftVec);//recursive call
        vector<T> right=sort(rightVec);//recursive call

        vector<T>FinalVec;//this will be the final vector that is returned

        FinalVec=merge(left,right);//will merge and sort when all the vectors  
//getting issues here^^^^^
        return FinalVec;

    }


}

private:
template <class T>
vector<T> merge (vector<T> left,vector<T> right)

{
    //some code here
    return final;

}



};
```

Issue i'm getting is when I try to do

**FinalVec=merge(left,right);

Error i'm getting is:

> error: cannot call member function ‘std::vector
>   MergeSort::merge(std::vector, std::vector) [with T = int]’
>   without object
>          FinalVec=merge(left,right);//

In my main i try to do:

> vector gooz;
>
> gooz.push_back(7);
>
> gooz.push_back(5);
>
> gooz.push_back(4);
>
> gooz.push_back(3);
>
> gooz.push_back(2);
>
> gooz.push_back(1);
>
> gooz=MergeSort::sort(gooz);
>
> //or even using it on an object of MergeSort won't work;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be because you have declared the

```
vector<T> merge (vector<T> left,vector<T> right)
```

as private so can not call from the **Main** method.

inside **static vector sort (vector a)** its expecting object because **sort** is a static method while **merge** is not static.  Try to call from **sort** using object or make **merg** as static

Comment: made merge static and it worked!! Just curious what does static entail? I'm not too clear on what a it means when used for a function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in very short I will say static mean signal copy of member/method even having many copy of the class.  better practice if writing a utility class which perform some operation and doesn't bother about the status of object.. try to make it static.. what is static? it gonna be good to read about it for you.. to call the static method, no need to create the object of class if method is static.. 

**if above answer solved ur problem don't forget to make it as an answer so that other can also find it useful.**

Comment: Done! So if I am understanding correctly, a static function usually means the class it belongs to is for the purpose of doing something to an external element and not for the reason of actually having an object of it.

Comment: (y) perfect.. we can treat it is utility class/method which generally performs a task for other object.. or for itself as well but it really requires.. like a class where we need to maintain the count of created object of that class. so we will have a variable **int count** as static, mean this will be shared between call the object of that class..  hope it make sense to you..